# Moving notes and lists (in reminders) from iphone 7 to iphone 12

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

My new phone has my photos and my music, but not my notes or my reminders. The sim card has been moved to my new phone (if that is important). How do I copy these items?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to sync data like this is via iCloud (or another web service of your choice).

The Apple methods to move data don’t merge backups, it’s all or nothing so since you already have data on the new phone, you want to sync and not migrate.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/set-up-icloud-mail-on-your-devices-mmdd8d1d47/icloud

You can turn on each category you want to sync. I recommend starting with the old device first, then the new second.

[image: iCloud settings on iOS 14]